# Begin root process at boot?

Tags: linux, startup, daemon

I'd like to start a background process as root when my Linux install boots. Can I just add it to a directory or a configuration file?

Answer (score 5):

Basically you have two options:

1. use a `cron` job with `@reboot` time specification (see `crontab(1)` man-page for details)
2. start it by the init system. For BSD/SysV init style this means adding a script somewhere to be run in the desired runlevel. For systemd, this involves creating a unit file and requiring it by the desired target.

The first solution is better for things local to one or two machines (since they are more of a configuration thing); the second one is suited for service/daemon like things that are likely to be run on more systems -- and should actually be packaged to make maintenance easier.

Comment: Just `@reboot command` at the end of the `crontab -e` file?

Comment: @tkbx Yes, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run a process as root at boot time is to start it from `/etc/rc.local`. Edit that file and add a line like

```
/path/to/my/daemon &
```

However this is not a very good way of starting a daemon. You get no convenient way to control it (check whether it's running, stop it, restart it, etc.).

There are several frameworks to control daemons. They are tied to your init system: Sysvinit, Upstart, Systemd each have their way. Check what is installed on your system (it varies between unix variants, and for Linux, it varies by distribution and by administrator choice).